# Register a Global keyboard Shotcut

Tags: electron

I was recently going thorugh Github's Electron documentation. One of the examples they use

```
const electron = require('electron') const app = electron.app const dialog = electron.dialog const globalShortcut = electron.globalShortcut

app.on('ready', function () {   globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Alt+K', function () {
    dialog.showMessageBox({
      type: 'info',
      message: 'Success!',
      detail: 'You pressed the registered global shortcut keybinding.',
      buttons: ['OK']
    })   }) })

app.on('will-quit', function () {   globalShortcut.unregisterAll() })
```

which seemed like a cross platform solution for keyboard hooks. But the above example registers the keyboard shortcut globally. It is possible to in a way register all the keystrokes without hindering the user? For instance, if I were to press . 'ctrl+w' on my web browser I want the my electon app to register ctrl+w. But not the hinder its function on a weeb browser.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Electron team has taken a look at possible implementations of this feature and have rejected [a related github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1338) as *won't fix* due to security and usability concerns.

Comment: Could you please repost the link. It doesn't seem to be working right now?

Comment: Sure, fixed the link